# Creating non clustered index in sql server in large table

Tags: sql-server, nonclustered-index

Table is having 180 million records. Has a primary key(WExtractGrouping, Id, PEventId, CAId, TEventId, EventDate). No other indexes except clustered index on pk.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Event_WLastUpdated_1] 
ON [dbo].[Event] ([WLastUpdated])
```

The query is running still running its been 7 hours. When ran exec sp_who2 It shows status as RUNNABLE CPUTime - 210641 DiskIO - 21840949 Command - CREATE INDEX.

For another run it shows status as SUSPENDED
CPUTime - 210641 DiskIO - 21840949 Command - CREATE INDEX

I see diskIO and CPU are increasing with time. Is there any problem, or is it expected. Why is that going to suspended? How much time does it take. What is the best way to create this index?

Comment: If you want that index there isn't much you can do other than get faster disks

Comment: What is the data type of `WLastUpdated`? Could you please post the table definition of the `dbo.Event` table? Also could you post your server specs for this SQL Server instance?